# Date pattern is not working in Logstash

Tags: regex, date, pattern-matching, logstash

In Logstash, is there a built-in date pattern for the following date format:

`01 Jan 2014 20:38:07,040`

If not, what pattern should be used in `pattern dir`?

I can't figure out how to write the `dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS` pattern in the custom pattern file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH} %{YEAR} %{TIME}`. Give it a shot. Does not look like a standard grok pattern. https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ is a good tool to use for working through these.

Comment: thanks :) Is there anyway to find out list of all existing (inbuilt) logstash patterns?

Comment: You can see the patterns in github here: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/tree/master/patterns